# WWW::Mechanize timeout - all urls timing out

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am having a problem using WWW::Mechanize.  It seems no matter what website I try accessing, my script just sits there in the command prompt until it times out.  The only things that come to mind that might be relevant are the following:

- I have IE7, chrome, and FF installed.  FF was my default browser but I recently switched that to chrome.
- I seem to be able to access websites with port 8080 just fine.
- I recently experimented with the cookie jar but stopped using it because, honestly, I'm not sure how it works.  This may have instantiated a change.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/learn/';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url );

print $mech->content;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work, so it must be a firewall/proxy issue. You can try setting a proxy:

```
   $mech->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://your-proxy:8080/');
```